# Pandas: Group by rounded floating number

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with a column of floating numbers. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randn(100), 'B': np.random.randn(100)})
```

What I want to do is to group by column A after rounding column A to 2 decimal places.

The way I do it is highly inefficient:

```
df.groupby(df.A.map(lambda x: "%.2f" % x))
```

I particularly don't want to convert everything to a string, as speed becomes a huge problem. But I don't feel it is safe to do the following:

```
df.groupby(np.around(df.A, 2))
```

I am not sure, but I feel that there might be cases where two float64 numbers will have the same string representation after rounding to 2 decimal places, but might have slightly different representations when np.around to 2 decimal places. For example, is it possible a string representation of 1.52 can be represented by np.around(., 2) as 1.52000001 sometimes but  1.51999999 some other times?

My question is what is a better and more efficient way.

Comment: Could you just multiply column `A` by 100 and convert to integers? Like `df.groupby(pd.Series(np.int64(df.A * 100)))`? Then just divide by 100.0 to get the original values.

Comment: I assume I could, but it is by no means convenient.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### I think you not need to convert float to string.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : map(lambda x: random(), range(100000)), 'B': map(lambda x: random(), range(100000))})
df.groupby(df['A'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 1))).count()
```

Comment: If only counts are needed, then value_counts would be the way to go: ```df['A'].round(1).value_counts()```